# when using nestjs throttler, I can't seem to import the right testmodule to run the unit test

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm currently getting the following error when trying to utilize `nestjs/throttler`,

```
 Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MyThrottlerGuard (?, Symbol(ThrottlerStorage), Reflector). Please make sure that the argument THROTTLER:MODULE_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the RootTestModule context.

    Potential solutions:
    - If THROTTLER:MODULE_OPTIONS is a provider, is it part of the current RootTestModule?
    - If THROTTLER:MODULE_OPTIONS is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within RootTestModule?
      @Module({
        imports: [ /* the Module containing THROTTLER:MODULE_OPTIONS */ ]
      })
```

Comment: What are you testing? What does your test setup look like?